# How to enable EMERGENCY_PARSER in Marlin firmware?

Tags: marlin

In the documentation of some commands of the Marlin firmware (like [M112 - Emergency Stop](http://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/M112.html)), it says that the `EMERGENCY_PARSER` should be enabled to execute them instantaneously.

The thing is, I didn't find any information there of **how to enable** that `EMERGENCY_PARSER` or how it works.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The constant `EMERGENCY_PARSER` is located in the advanced printer configuration file [Marlin/Configuration_adv.h](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/blob/1.1.x/Marlin/Configuration_adv.h):

```
// Enable an emergency-command parser to intercept certain commands as they
// enter the serial receive buffer, so they cannot be blocked.
// Currently handles M108, M112, M410
// Does not work on boards using AT90USB (USBCON) processors!
//#define EMERGENCY_PARSER
```

To enable the `EMERGENCY_PARSER`, you need to remove the `//` before `#define EMERGENCY_PARSER` and recompile the sources.

Normally your printer will execute a command until it is ready to accept a next instruction. Without the `EMERGENCY_PARSER` set, the printer finishes the instruction that it is executing at the moment, if set, the execution is interrupted and immediately sent and thus not waiting for a clear space in the buffer.

Comment: Is there a way to know if `EMERGENCY_PARSER` is set without looking at the printer configuration file (for example, sending a command or checking the first responses when you connect via serial port)? Was this feature added on Marlin 1.1.0?

Comment: @fsinisi90 I don't know if you could try that out. You do need to somehow inject the `M112` in the midst of operation, usually that is done by the code as an emergency response on certain limit checks, I do not know how to insert that manually from outside.

Comment: Well, I've already tried with `M190` (wait for bed temperature) and then `M108` and it's not working, but my firmware is Marlin 1.0.3 and I guess the `EMERGENCY_PARSER` was added on 1.1.0, so I don't even have the possibility to enable it. Anyway, I was looking for a way to check it on any printer from my source code (I'm connecting through pyserial), without human intervention.